# Facebook Timeline shared post not showing properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline, fb.ui

when I try to share a message to Facebook wall using fb.ui, if I didn't enter any message, the post will not appear in timeline but it did appear at my friends' News Feed. I've check activity log, the post activity is there, but it just did not appear in my timeline unless I put a personal/customized message myself. Did anyone encounter this? Just wondering whether it is a bug or it is supposed to be working that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, Facebook filters the feed with their own algorithms.  If it's the feed of the developer it will always be shown from what I've read.  It will always be in the activity log, but not necessarily shown on a friend's feed (non-developer) based upon facebook's own algorithms.